# Can we upload photos from phone`s camera with HTML5

Tags: spring, html, spring-mvc

Hi folks can we upload photos from phone`s camera just with pure HTML5? Can we use Spring Mobile to develop html5 applications?

Thank you heaps man!!!

Comment: This are 2 questions and should be divided, see FAQ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can! Pls look at the link.

[W3 Media capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/)

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

You can take photos on Android phones and upload them using built in Chrome Browser. I've tested it on Android 2.0 and above. On IOS 3.X, IOS 4.X, IOS 5.X this option is disabled inside the safari browser (thanks for comments on this). On IOS 6.X this is working as expected.

You don't need HTML5. Use a simple file upload form for that:

```
<input name="picture" type="file" size="50" maxlength="100000" accept="img/*">
```

Comment: File upload is disabled in all current versions of iOS, so this is not possible in Mobile Safari on an iPhone / iPad yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have tried using the phonegap API's?

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: Not "pure HTML5" though is it? You can only use these APIs when your mark-up and Javascript are wrapped up as a PhoneGap application.

Comment: True but it does cover a lot of platforms.